# The best way to protect a website for company management

Tags: html

I have a website that is already protected by Windows NT Challenge Response when anyone tries to go there.

Many years ago I had a create a special webpage that required extra security

I put in:

Hey all, I have given up trying to convince this system to accept a paste of the real html code so here it is with html tags removed:

START

Please logon:

form name=form1 method=post action=HIDDEN

UserName:

input type=password name=UserName

Password:

input type=password name=Password

input type=submit name=Submit value=Logon

END

And thought nothing of it until a recent meeting when a member of staff using the webpage complained that it was a nuisance, he wanted that information to be auto filled in by his web browser

So the Challenge Response was being auto filled in by his web browser, but the code posted above then stopped him/her getting to the webpage without typing the required security codes

I have spent some time looking to see if what I say above has been pointed out before, and found nothing

So using

input type=password for both username and password

Is a method that should be in general use on very secure sites

Phil

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: my question is "why do company websites not use the very secure method that I found by accident years ago"? No way should one allow a web browser to bypass security and auto fill in the username and password

Comment: Because some people don't know what they're doing, what technology is available, or how to implement technology/processes effectively. This is a philosophical question (and seemingly a rhetorical one since there is no real answer.)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for commenting, well I am talking about company websites here , like those the MDs go to  , not "some people"

Comment: I have spent some time looking to see if what I say above has been pointed out before, and found nothing, sums it up: my research included several national security organism's guidelines for webpages

Answer (score 0):

If you're on IIS with Windows auth/pass-through authentication (think that's what it's called), you should be able to just set the permissions on the file itself on the file system to limit the users to access it.

If you want to keep your current wildly secure method, you could use JS to stash the values in a cookie and use that populate the form on page load.

Comment: I have spent some time looking to see if what I say above has been pointed out before, and found nothing, sums it up: my research included several national security organism's guidelines for webpages

Comment: Sorry, my point is probably at the more fundamental level - why aren't you just using the NT authentication - what's the 'more secure' system doing that you couldn't just use OOTB? Of course, you might be authenticating these codes to a separate auth provider, but it sounded like you're just securing some web pages on the IIS server; in which case just simplify and use IIS/NT for that and it'll remove the username/password which is causing the pain.

Comment: because the browser offers to fill them in automatically hence bypassing all security

Comment: Well, it's not bypassing the security - you're still supplying the right credentials, but I think all browsers offer this 'help' to users so if you want to force them to manually log in then your method is it.

Comment: Just saw this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion but this is only available in newer browsers though.

Comment: Interesting article marcus

Comment: The section:
“Even without a master password, in-browser password management is generally seen as a net gain for security. Since users don't have to remember passwords that the browser stores for them, they are able to choose stronger passwords than they would otherwise.
For this reason, many modern browsers do not support autocomplete="off" for login fields”

Explains things.